# How to calculate $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sqrt x - x^2}{1-\sqrt x}$ without L'Hopital rule?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sqrt x - x^2}{1-\sqrt x}$$

I solved it by using L'hopital and got $3$. 

 I've also attempted to solve it without L'hopital, but unfortunately I couldn't.

Comment: Would you be able to do it with substitution $t = \sqrt x$?

Comment: Could you try partial fraction? I feel the denominator can divide the numerator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:** Use
$$\sqrt{x}-x^2=\sqrt{x}(1-\sqrt{x}^3)=\sqrt{x}(1-\sqrt{x})(1+\sqrt{x}+x)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sqrt x-x^2}{1-\sqrt x}=\frac{(\sqrt x -x)+(x-x\sqrt x)+(x\sqrt x-x^2)}{1-\sqrt x}=\sqrt x+x+x\sqrt x$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: After taking $\sqrt{x}$ common, use the formula $(a+b)^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$ for $a=1,b=-x^{1/2}$.

Comment: Oops! same idea used :p